# In list view arrayadapters in my adapter class i am not able to retrieve the list using the data class and array is already defined in main activity

Tags: kotlin, android-arrayadapter

Following are my classes

DataEtc

```
data class DataEtc(
    val names: String,
    val image: Int
)
```

MyEtcAdapter.kt

```
class CustomAdapter(private val context: Activity, dataEtcs: Array<DataEtc>) : ArrayAdapter<DataEtc>(context, R.layout.show_list_etc, dataEtcs) {

  override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup): View {
    val inflater = context.layoutInflater
    val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_list_etc, null, false)
    val titleText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.srctext) as TextView
    val imageView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.srcimage) as ImageView

    titleText.setText(DataEtc[p0].names)
    imageView.setImageResource(DataEtc[p0].image)


    return rowView
  }
}
```

The following error is coming while running this code.

Classifier 'DataEtc' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Comment: Please add what the problem is or is there any error you are getting

Comment: titleText.setText(DataEtc[p0].names)
    imageView.setImageResource(DataEtc[p0].image)
error in these 2 lines.
How should i implement or call my variables in array adapter such that my list appears.(i am new to android studio)

Comment: But what is the error even your question or the comment doesn't help in understanding this

Comment: Classifier 'DataEtc' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here.
This is the error i am getting.\

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are using `DataEtc` that is the class name to access the element at index p0 instead you have to use `dataEtcs[p0]` which is the name of your Array